# ok button for alert in mac app does not work

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-sheet

On a button click, I am using the below code

```
testViewController *myWindowController  = [[testViewController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"RecordingsViewController"];

[myWindowController setDelegate:self];
activeModalWindow = [myWindowController window];

[NSApp beginSheet:[myWindowController window]
   modalForWindow:[self window]
    modalDelegate:self
   didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
      contextInfo:nil];
[NSApp runModalForWindow:[myWindowController window]];

[[myWindowController window] orderOut: self];
```

From this testViewController, I am showing an alert using the code

```
NSString *theAlertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already added"];
NSRunAlertPanel(@"", theAlertMessage, @"OK", nil, nil);
```

But on clicking ok button of this alert. My alert remains on screen. Please help!

Comment: strange, this works for me, do you have error/warning messages in debugger console?

Comment: can you please try to build new project with simple frame using NSRunAlertPanel to verify its functionality in your system? (to exclude chance that problem is only in this project)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to as :

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setAlertStyle:2];
[alert setMessageText:@"Already added"];

    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[(AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]
                   modalDelegate:self

                  didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                     contextInfo:nil];
 }

 - (void)sheetDidEnd:(NSAlert *)alert
               returnCode:(int)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    NSLog(@"clicked %d button\n", returnCode);

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative, it works perfectly

```
NSString *theAlertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already added."];
NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
[alert setAlertStyle:NSCriticalAlertStyle];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[alert setMessageText:theAlertMessage];
```